# What is the contrast used in calculating the $2^p$ ANOVA table? ${{}}$

Tags: statistics

According to my statistics textbook, you need the contrast of each effect and interaction in order to compute the sum of squares (for ANOVA) of that effect/interaction. Unfortunately, it never explains what contrast is.

Here are how the contrasts are calculated for each effect/interaction in a $2^3$ experiment:

\begin{align}
\text{Contrast}_A & =-\overline{X}_{1} + \overline{X}_A - \overline{X}_{B} - \overline{X}_{C} + \overline{X}_{AB} + \overline{X}_{AC} - \overline{X}_{BC} + \overline{X}_{ABC}\\[6pt]
\text{Contrast}_B & =-\overline{X}_{1} - \overline{X}_A + \overline{X}_{B} - \overline{X}_{C} + \overline{X}_{AB} - \overline{X}_{AC} + \overline{X}_{BC} + \overline{X}_{ABC}\\[6pt]
\text{Contrast}_C & =-\overline{X}_{1} - \overline{X}_A - \overline{X}_{B} + \overline{X}_{C} - \overline{X}_{AB} + \overline{X}_{AC} + \overline{X}_{BC} + \overline{X}_{ABC}\\[6pt]
\text{Contrast}_{AB} & =\overline{X}_{1} - \overline{X}_A - \overline{X}_{B} + \overline{X}_{C} + \overline{X}_{AB} - \overline{X}_{AC} - \overline{X}_{BC} + \overline{X}_{ABC}\\[6pt]
\text{Contrast}_{AC} & =\overline{X}_{1} - \overline{X}_A + \overline{X}_{B} - \overline{X}_{C} - \overline{X}_{AB} + \overline{X}_{AC} - \overline{X}_{BC} + \overline{X}_{ABC}\\[6pt]
\text{Contrast}_{BC} & =\overline{X}_{1} + \overline{X}_A - \overline{X}_{B} - \overline{X}_{C} - \overline{X}_{AB} - \overline{X}_{AC} + \overline{X}_{BC} + \overline{X}_{ABC}\\[6pt]
\text{Contrast}_{ABC} & =-\overline{X}_{1} + \overline{X}_A + \overline{X}_{B} + \overline{X}_{C} - \overline{X}_{AB} - \overline{X}_{AC} - \overline{X}_{BC} + \overline{X}_{ABC}
\end{align}

The sum of squares is calculated with $\text{SS} = \dfrac{(\#\text{replicates per group}) \cdot \text{contrast}^2}{2^3}$

So what is contrast?

Comment: it seems to be difficult to say something with the information provided in the question

Comment: @MichaelHardy you always disagree with me. why? because I do not know standard things. you've told me this already right? do you have something new? what is $X_1$? $A$, $B$... whatever. Better have a look at my last question and let me know your ideas. thx.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören : If I always disagree with you, that had escaped my notice.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören $A$, $B$, $C$ are the different factors of the experiment. In a $2^p$ experiment, all the factors have two different levels. $X_1$ represents the group of replicates that have "low" levels of each factor. $X_{ABC}$ represents the group of replicates that have "high" levels of each factor.

Answer (score 1):

What I think is the most frequently seen definition (but I haven't checked all the books, even among those I have at hand) is this:

> A contrast is a linear combination in which the *sum* of the coefficients is $0$, but not all coefficients are $0$.

A bit more precisely, if you multiply all the coefficients by the same scalar, it's not really a different contrast, e.g. if the coefficients are $2, -1, -1$, that's really the same contrast as $4,-2,-2$.

Contrasts among averages of different populations or among estimates of those averages assess the ways in which they differ from each other. For example $2,-1,-1$ would measure the diffence between the first population and the average of the second and third.

Your example involves a three-factor anova. Your first contrast differs significantly from $0$ if there is a significant difference between the two levels of factor $A$. That is because all of the terms corresponding to one of the two levels of factor $A$ have plus signs and those corresponding to the other level have a minus sign. The one with the subscript $AB$ differs significantly from $0$ if there is significant evidence of interaction between those two factors. Etc.

Comment: I've just checked about eight books.  All of them omit to mention that the linear combination in which _all_ coefficients are $0$ is to be excluded. But that is obvious. All of them also omit to say that a scalar multiple of a contrast is really the same contrast. But I'm guessing all of the authors would instantly agree with that. One of those I checked was the famous book by Henry Scheffé.

Comment: Can you explain why the coefficients were chosen the way they were in my book and why the sum of squares is able to be calculated that way? The book I have been learning from is called Statistics for Engineers and Scientists, 4th edition by William Navidi.

Comment: @TheNumberOne : As I said "all of the terms corresponding to one of the two levels of factor $A$ have plus signs and those corresponding to the other level have a minus sign". That's the reason for the signs in the contrasts for effects of $A$, $B$, and $C$. Now look at the $AB$ interaction. For this to be absent means this: You have four cells: one oof the lower levels of both $A$ and $B$, one for the lower level of $A$ and the higher level of $B$, one for the lower level of $B$ and the higher level of $A$, and one for the higher levels of both, and you take the$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$average for the lower levels of both, and add something to it to get the average for the higher level of $A$, and add something else to get that for the higher level of $B$, and add both to get the cell with the higher levels of both.  The presence of the $AB$ interaction means that last one doesn't work: so you add something else if you're at either the $1$ or $AB$ and subtract it if you're at $A$ or $B$. That explains the coefficients for the $AB$ interaction. $\qquad$